# Split Audio File for sentences speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Many advances have been done in the field of Speech Recogntion. Most recent systems are recognizing only a small chunk of audio (4-10 seconds), which are assumed to be full sentences. This is good for training, but not for inference at production while we may get a long audio file (e.g. 1 hour) and we want to apply ASR on it.

Typical approach is to apply a speech splitter like [`py-webrtcvad`](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py) to get the audio splitted. However,

1) The sound maybe breaked at the middle of a word that is said very slow

2) The speaker may speak very fast, so will give 1-2 minutes chunks. And as said, cannot deal with that long chunks (only 4-10 seconds are ok).

How can I split audio for Speech Recognition? Is there any tool for that?

Comment: Can you share sample sound file?

Comment: The technique you are looking for is Voice Activity Detection (VAD). There are so many ways to do this that a stack overflow answer could not really help, I would suggest a little more research and then come back with specific problems.